# segfault error 4 in libc-2.11.1.so

Tags: ubuntu, glibc, segmentation-fault

Key Info: Ubuntu 64 Lucid (No memory issues, no new hardware)

Nearly every application dies with this segfault. Googling around finds dozens of posts that have this exact problem and not a single solution so hopefully you guys can give me a hand.

Example GDB of synaptic:

```
Starting program: /usr/sbin/synaptic
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff31a1280 in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
```

Comment: Did u manage to resolve your problem? I ran into the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you can start aptitude/dpkg, try reinstalling (`aptitude reinstall`) or rolling back the `libc6-i686` package.

Comment: Yup, tried to no avail. That is, I successfully reinstalled with apt-get install --reinstall libc6 but it didn't do anything

Comment: Did you tried rolling it back to a previous version?

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact, it made things quite massively worse. Rolling back libc forces an uninstall of virtually every major package in the system. Est no bueno